# How to add to windows contextual menu Open Command Prompt (Shell)

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, context-menu

Recently I worked under linux and there is a feature that I like very much. 
I can open a shell by making right click inside the window and choosing a corresponding option from menu.
Is there a way to add something similar in Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>right-click</kbd> in the folder (not on a file) you should see the option

> 'Open a Command Window here'

Available in [Vista and above](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/22/4500831.aspx).

See also [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/109/1/How-to-add-Open-Command-Window-Here-context-menu-option-on-file-system-folders-in-Windows-Vista.html)

Comment: what windows versions does this apply to?  it's not available in default XP, for example.

Comment: Windows 7 there is this option.

Answer (score 3):

there are a few methods, [outlined in this link](http://www.petri.co.il/add_command_prompt_here_shortcut_to_windows_explorer.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's set of [PowerToys for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) includes a tool that provides an [Open Command Window Here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/whistler/Install/2/WXP/EN-US/CmdHerePowertoySetup.exe) context menu item.